# Why do I keep getting the following two errors when I try to open a(ny) document in Office 2010?

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-office-2010

it doesn't seem to matter what document, where I obtain the document, or what kind of document it is.. and then the document fails to open after I get the two screens... also, I made a realization that it only seems to effect `.doc` files, I can open up `.docx` files and other various files.

First
[image]

Then
[image]

Comment: There is a _similar_ problem discussed [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-CA/office2010/thread/8d7371ac-1e4c-4ae7-8c99-c5605c21593a).

Comment: I tried their suggestions, didn't work, but thanks.

Comment: Have you checked the suggestions offered by Word in the 2nd dialog?

Comment: Yes I have even uninstalled office and reinstalled it...Also, I can open the documents on my laptop, which has office 2010 so I don't think it is the documents that are the problem...

Comment: That text is so small and blurry it's hard to read what it even says

Answer (score 0):

The first message is called "protected mode"

http://www.webtlk.com/2010/01/04/how-to-turn-off-protected-view-in-office-2010/

> One of the newest features in Office 2010 is the new “Protected View” which protects your operating system from those unsafe documents downloaded from the Internet or suspicious Outlook email attachments which fail validation. If any of these documents are detected by Office 2010, the system will open them in a “Read-Only” way, thus diminishing the risk to be infected by malware or viruses.f I, for any reason, you do not like such a feature,  here is a simple tutorial to disable it in a couple of steps.
>
> Open Word or Excel in Office 2010.
>
> Click the Office button. Go to File Menu, Office Backstage,  and click Options.
> In the left pane, Click Trust Center.
>
> Now, on the right pane, click the Trust Center Settings button.
>
> At this point you should be in the Trust Center dialog window.
>
> In the left pane, click Protected View.
>
> Untick the following options:
>
> Enable Protected View for files that fail validation
>
> Enable Protected View for files originating from the Internet
>
> Enable Protected View for files located in potentially unsafe locations
>
> Enable Protected View for Outlook attachments
>
> Click OK.

.

Second error

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-GB/word/thread/5e74e0dc-4e5f-4e19-9797-eb6b4e64be13

Right click on the word document and select properties, hit the "unblock" button

.

You can also try a repair of Office

http://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-repair-office-2010-or-uninstall-individual-office-2010-programs

.

.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but neither solution worked...

Comment: Check my edit above.